# jquery $.get warning synchronous xmlhttprequest on main thread with simple html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

When executing a jquery $.get() call to retrieve an html file that includes a script tag with a src attribute, I am getting the warning "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience." in Firefox's console. Here is some simple code that I used to narrow down the warning that demonstrates this:

foo.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>$.get("bar.html", function(data) { $('#testdiv').html(data);});</script>
<div id="testdiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

bar.html

```
<script src="foo.js"></script>
```

Note that foo.js is empty, so nothing in there seems to be causing the warning. I don't understand the reason for this. Would anybody know what's causing this?

Answer (score 2):

I started to wholly investigate this issue myself and the warning is being generated by your browser when JQuery dynamically loads a page that contains a script tag with a reference to an external script.

So, in your case, foo.html loads bar.html and as your browser begins to parse the content from bar.html it encounters `<script src="foo.js"></script>` which causes the browser to stop parsing content, load and execute `foo.js`.  If you don't have any code in `foo.js`, you won't notice any detriments to performance, but if your browser takes any discernible amount of time to parse and execute `foo.js` then your end user will actually lose control of the browser (meaning the browser will appear to be frozen) until foo.js finishes executing.  This is what is meant by the warning's message: `detrimental effects to the end user's experience`.

The work around that I am considering is to implement custom events to trigger the relevant pieces of my code at the proper time which is probably a better idea to begin with.  I am curious to know if anyone else has any clever ways of circumventing the issue.